# how to align a switch to centre and a text view to right end in a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have a linear layout which is in horizontal orientation and weight sum is 3 with 2 text views at the left and right ends and a switch in the middle. I am not able to align the text view to the right end and the switch to the center. I have used gravity center and gravity end but they are not working

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/rm_dashboard_ll_padding"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/available"
             android:textColor="#82BCB4"
             android:textSize="@dimen/available_textsize"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Switch
             android:id="@+id/theSwitchId"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:switchMinWidth="@dimen/rm_switch_minwidth"
             android:track="@drawable/switch_bg"
             android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_start_switch"
             android:thumbTint="#224e6d"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_switch"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/unavailable"
             android:textColor="#224e6d"
             android:textSize="@dimen/unavailable_textsize"
             android:layout_gravity="end"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? any screenshots?

Comment: in your code I just add `android:gravity="right"` this and it work for me

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `RelativeLayout` for complex alignments. Try layout model below:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
    <Switch
        android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For detail information about another alignment types see [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/rm_dashboard_ll_padding"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/available"
            android:textColor="#82BCB4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/available_textsize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/theSwitchId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:switchMinWidth="@dimen/rm_switch_minwidth"
            android:track="@drawable/switch_bg"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_start_switch"
            android:thumbTint="#224e6d"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_switch"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/unavailable"
            android:textColor="#224e6d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/unavailable_textsize"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it is working but I wanted to put switch in the centre @Akash